# Is there a way to equalize the histogram of a 16-bits per sample image using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am working with 16bits/sample images.
Is there a (simple) way to perform the histogram equalization of such images (converting to 8bps is not an option)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`equalizeHist` in OpenCV takes only 8 bit data.

but image normalization in OpenCV is not limited to 8 bit data. See its description [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=normalize#normalize).In your case call to function should look like:

```
normalize(src_image, dst_image, 0, 65535, NORM_MINMAX);
```

if you are trying to improve contrast of image, first try normalization and only if this is not working try equalization. Normalization is faster and less destructive.

refer to : http://answers.opencv.org/question/3176/improve-contrast-of-a-16u-image/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, images are already normalized (0-65535) but with majority of samples in 5000-9000 range. Thank you.

Comment: Well, on a second thought, I could make a simple non-linear transformation that would spread the 5000-9000 range of values and shrink two remaining ranges of values with low frequency (low number of occurrences). I just found out that the same answers lies in the linked thread you referred to. Anyway, thank you for the idea :)

Answer (score 5):

As of now, OpenCV equalizeHist only support 8 bit images. I have created 16 bit histogram equalization function [here](https://github.com/syaifulnizamyahya/HistogramEqualization16Bit) based on OpenCV implementation [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp).

```
void equalizeHist16Bit(const cv::Mat &_src, cv::Mat &_dst)
{
    _dst = _src.clone();

    const int hist_sz = 65536;
    int *hist = new int[hist_sz] {};
    int *lut = new int[hist_sz] {};

    for (int y = 0; y < _src.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < _src.cols; x++)
            hist[(int)_src.at<unsigned short int>(y, x)]++;

    auto i = 0;
    while (!hist[i]) ++i;

    auto total = (int)_src.total();
    if (hist[i] == total) 
    {
        _dst.setTo(i);
        return;
    }

    float scale = (hist_sz - 1.f) / (total - hist[i]);
    auto sum = 0;

    for (lut[i++] = 0; i < hist_sz; ++i) 
    {
        sum += hist[i];
        lut[i] = cv::saturate_cast<ushort>(sum * scale);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < _src.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < _src.cols; x++)
        {
            _dst.at<unsigned short int>(y, x) = lut[(int)_src.at<unsigned short int>(y, x)];
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can I check how do I implement this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation in python
Reference: https://github.com/torywalker/histogram-equalizer/blob/master/HistogramEqualization.ipynb

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_tif=cv2.imread("scan.tif",cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
img = np.asarray(img_tif)
flat = img.flatten()
hist = get_histogram(flat,65536)
#plt.plot(hist)

cs = cumsum(hist)
# re-normalize cumsum values to be between 0-255

# numerator & denomenator
nj = (cs - cs.min()) * 65535
N = cs.max() - cs.min()

# re-normalize the cdf
cs = nj / N
cs = cs.astype('uint16')
img_new = cs[flat]
#plt.hist(img_new, bins=65536)
#plt.show(block=True)
img_new = np.reshape(img_new, img.shape)
cv2.imwrite("contrast.tif",img_new)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please elaborate what this code does and how it helps to resolve the issue. Code-only answers are considered a bit bad quality here and should be coupled with some explanation.

Comment: This does not work for me